# XRDP Logout works on 12.04m fails on 14.04

Tags: permissions, logout, xrdp

I am using XRDP service to remote into several machines.  A machine running 12.04, I can remote into, and when I complete work I can logout, and it logs out just fine.  For a machine running 14.04, I hit logout, and the screen clears like its going to logout, but then just sits there.  I can disconnect from this xrdp session, but the session does not die.  When I relogin with a new xrdp session, the port number jumps up indicating the old session is still active.  If I login to the original session's port number it brings up the blank screen still hanging on the logout.  one or 2 times it popped up an error box saying the user had insufficient priveleges to perform the action, so I'm wondring if there is some permission that needs setting or changing. I searched and could not find anything that helped.